# Get a linear second order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

This question may seems naive, but I still learn calculus: The following equation is a second-order differential equation, since it contains a derivative $h''$, but is it a linear differential equation?

[image]

The complete equation's Mathematica file link is:
[Mathematica file of the equation](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnEacJl3zmDWgk4Eo4R_MAtwx4x2?e=e8va2z)

If it is non-linear differential equation, how to make it linear by MA?

For instance to collect only ($h$) terms, I tried `Collect[Gij,h]` but it returns the same equation, or also `Coefficient`

---

```
(E^y*a[t]^2*(-2*(1 + h[t, y] - 2*h[t, y]^2)^2*Derivative[0, 1][f][t, y]*(1 + h[t, y] + Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]) + 
    f[t, y]*(6 + 27*h[t, y]^5 + 8*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] - 3*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 + 
      h[t, y]^3*(-54 - 26*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] + 7*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 - 16*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y]) + 
      4*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y] + h[t, y]*(18 + 4*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] - 5*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 + 
        8*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y]) + h[t, y]^4*(-3 + 50*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] + 16*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y]) + 
      h[t, y]^2*(-48*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] + 13*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 - 12*(1 + Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y])))))/
  (4*f[t, y]^3*(-1 + h[t, y])^2*(1 + 2*h[t, y])^2)
```

Comment: your latex does not match the screen shot of your Mathematica code. In your code you write `h[t,y]` but in your latex you write $h'$.  Is this supposed to be a pde or an ode?  The ode is non-linear if the dependent variable enters as non-linear. Something like $(h')^2$ or $h h'$ or $\frac{1}{h}$ or $\sin(h)$ and so on. So your ode (if it is an ode) is nonlinear. And it is better to post plain text version of your Mathematica code as it is a little hard to run code from an image. **how to make it linear by MA?** I do not understand this part of the question.

Comment: Hi @Nasser, please see the question edit. I tried in MA all Copy As options to copy a consistent form of the equation, but it didn't, so I made a link to the MA file and removed the Tex form. About my question, if this ode is non-linear, is there a way to collect only linear terms by MA, using Collect or Coefficient ?

Comment: fyi, I copied it from your notebook to your question. To copy it in the future, just convert to InputForm then copy as text.

Comment: You have terms up to forth order, so it is certainly not linear.

Comment: Hi @DanielHuber. The equation contains many terms, derivatives or orders of h, so is there as a way to pick up only linear terms? I mean I may intuitively set all $h^2, h^3,h^4$, $h^{’2}$, $ h’ h^3 $ terms to zero, but however I saw linear ode contains terms of order $h^2$

Comment: You could use a rule like: `h[t,y]^_ -> 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to linearize your ode assuming `h[t,y]<<1` try

```
ode = (E^y*
a[t]^2*(-2*(1 + h[t, y] - 2*h[t, y]^2)^2*
   Derivative[0, 1][f][t, 
    y]*(1 + h[t, y] + Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]) + 
  f[t, y]*(6 + 27*h[t, y]^5 + 8*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] - 
     3*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 + 
     h[t, y]^3*(-54 - 26*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] + 
        7*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 - 
        16*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y]) + 
     4*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y] + 
     h[t, y]*(18 + 4*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] - 
        5*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 + 
        8*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y]) + 
     h[t, y]^4*(-3 + 50*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] + 
        16*Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y]) + 
     h[t, y]^2*(-48*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y] + 
        13*Derivative[0, 1][h][t, y]^2 - 
        12*(1 + Derivative[0, 2][h][t, y])))))/(4*
f[t, y]^3*(-1 + h[t, y])^2*(1 + 2*h[t, y])^2)

odelin=Asymptotic[ode /. h -> Function[{t, y}, eps h[t, y]], {eps, 0, 2}] /.eps -> 1
```

We have to linearize up to order `eps^2` to keep second part of the ode.

"Linearized" second order `odelin`:

```
TeXForm[Collect[odelin, Derivative[n_][h][t, y], Expand]]
```

$-\frac{e^y a(t)^2 f^{(0,1)}(t,y) h^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^3}-\frac{e^y
   a(t)^2 f^{(0,1)}(t,y) h(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^3}-\frac{e^y a(t)^2
   f^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^3}-\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2 h^{(0,1)}(t,y)^2}{4
   f(t,y)^2}-\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2 h(t,y) h^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{f(t,y)^2}+\frac{2
   e^y a(t)^2 h^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{f(t,y)^2}+\frac{e^y a(t)^2
   h^{(0,2)}(t,y)}{f(t,y)^2}-\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2 h(t,y)^2}{2
   f(t,y)^2}+\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2 h(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^2}+\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2}{2
   f(t,y)^2}$

Hope it helps!

**addendum**

To get a linear pde (thanks to @MichaelSeifert's comment ) `Asymptotic` gives an unclear result, which surprisingly doesn't depend on `h[t,y]`

```
Asymptotic[ode /. h -> Function[{t, y}, eps h[t, y]], {eps, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

In contrast `Series` gives the expected result

```
odelin1 =Normal[Series [
ode /. h -> Function[{t, y}, eps h[t, y]], {eps, 0, 1}]] /.eps -> 1

TeXForm[Collect[odelin1, Derivative[n_][h][t, y], Expand]]
```

$-\frac{e^y a(t)^2 f^{(0,1)}(t,y) h^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^3}-\frac{e^y
   a(t)^2 f^{(0,1)}(t,y) h(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^3}-\frac{e^y a(t)^2
   f^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{2 f(t,y)^3}+\frac{2 e^y a(t)^2
   h^{(0,1)}(t,y)}{f(t,y)^2}+\frac{e^y a(t)^2
   h^{(0,2)}(t,y)}{f(t,y)^2}+\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2 h(t,y)}{2
   f(t,y)^2}+\frac{3 e^y a(t)^2}{2 f(t,y)^2}$

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. But the code doesn't run on MA12 that I use.

Comment: There is no `Asymptotic[]` in MA12.0, can we use `Series` instead?

Comment: @Dr.phy:  In earlier Mathematica versions, `odelin = Normal[Series[ode /. h -> Function[{t, y}, eps h[t, y]], {eps, 0, 2}]] /. eps -> 1` will give the same result.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you'd want to keep terms quadratic in `h` in a linear PDE.  If you don't, then change the `2` to a `1` in my snippet.  If you *only* want to have the linear equation, under the assumption that the "background" PDE for `f` an `a` is satisfied at zero order, use `odelin = Normal[SeriesCoefficient[ode /. h -> Function[{t, y}, eps h[t, y]], {eps, 0, 1}]] /. eps -> 1`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSeifert. I think that is right, cause as I understood $hh’$ and $h^{’2}$ are non-linear terms and there are no these terms when I use `{eps, 0, 1}`

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you for your helpful contribution. I only took `{eps,0,2}` because `Asymptotic[ode /. h -> Function[{t, y}, eps h[t, y]], {eps, 0, 1}]` didn't depend on `h[t,y]`

Comment: That's weird.  Seems like a bug, to be honest.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I think so too